# Backup GPOs basing on GPO DisplayName rather than Id

Tags: powershell, backup, gpo

So I am backing up all the GPOs of a Domain Controller and I noticed that the way Backup-GPO cmdlet backs up the GPOS is so unfriendly. By default it creates a folder for every single GPO named after the "ID" which doesn't even match its "GPOID/GUID".

Here is an example, I will just backup a specific GPO:

```
backup-gpo -guid ff8de365-0842-46ab-9ac7-64ebd8dd4614 -path C:\


DisplayName     : N12 Workstation Policy
GpoId           : ff8de365-0842-46ab-9ac7-64ebd8dd4614
Id              : dd33c220-bac8-4ebd-a9d9-7729fcea9c38
BackupDirectory : C:\
CreationTime    : 20/10/2015 17:41:43
DomainName      : martyn.local
```

This is the backup folder name that is created after issuing the previous command:

```
{DD33C220-BAC8-4EBD-A9D9-7729FCEA9C38}
```

If I try to Backup all the GPOs I get a folder for every single GPO. Is there any way of naming these folders basing on the GPO DisplayName rather than that unfriendly string?

This is what I would like to get:

```
N12 Workstation Policy
```

The reason why I want to do it like that is because if I want to re-import a single GPO in the future and I don't remember the name of the GPO how am I supposed to know which is the right GPO backup folder to import if I am using that awful name?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backup each GPO to separate subfolders of your backup folder:

```
$invalidChars = ':\\/' + [RegEx]::Escape(-join [IO.Path]::InvalidPathChars)

$backupDir = 'C:\backup'
Get-GPO -All | ForEach-Object {
  $name = $_.DisplayName -replace "[$invalidChars]", '_'
  $gpoDir = Join-Path $backupDir -ChildPath $name
  New-Item $gpoDir -Type Directory | Out-Null
  Backup-GPO -Guid $_.Id -Path $gpoDir
}
```

The replacement is to remove characters that are invalid in a path from the name (the creation of the subfolder would fail if the name of the GPO contained for instance a `>`). As @briantist suggested in his comment it's better to derive the list of invalid characters from the respective `IO.Path` property than maintain the list by hand. You may need to manually add other problematic characters, though, specifically `:`. The colon is used for accessing [alternate data streams](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx), so it's technically a valid character in a path, but PowerShell doesn't support it.

Comment: Great work; beat me to it. I like `$name = $_.DisplayName -creplace "[$([RegEx]::Escape(([System.IO.Path]::InvalidPathChars) -join ''))]", '_'` to ensure you replace everything.

Comment: @briantist Indeed. Fixed.

Comment: ooo nice use of unary `-join`!

Comment: I take my hat off to you guys, I've got a to learn a lot from you :)

Comment: Bad news, the previous script is crashing for a specific GPO named as "Mapped Drive M: \\Atlantis\Muser"

    New-Item : The given path's format is not supported.

This GPO is the unique that includes a colon ":" I think that $invalidChars doesn't take in consideration the ":" sign

Comment: The ':' error is sorted but it still doesn't work. It looks like now it doesn't find the path specified: Backup-GPO : The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
At C:\GPOBackup.ps1:76 char:13
+   Backup-GPO <<<<  -Guid $_.Id -Path $gpoDir

Comment: The folder created is named "Mapped Drive M_" shouldn't it be "Mapped Drive M_ __Atlantis_Muser"?

Comment: That depends on what the actual value of the `DisplayName` property is.

Comment: I noticed that too, DisplayName value is "Mapped Drive M_ \\Atlantis\Muser" that is why is crashing. This is the value of $invalidChars ":"<>\| ☺☻♥♦\t\n♂\f\r♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼"

Comment: '\' is part of $invalidChars, I just don't know why its not replacing it for '_'

Comment: Ah, no. The backslashes in that list escape the next characters (`\|` = literal pipe, `\t` = tab, `\n` = newline, etc.). You need to manually add ``\`` (and `/`) to `$invalidChars`. See updated answer.

Comment: sorted, this time worked like a charm. Thanks a million