# Create a CSV for each object using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am running vulnerability scans and I have a raw CSV file that I import. I remove the *Risk = None* from the file and then pull the information I need (**Name** of vulnerability, **Host**, **Risk**, **CVE**, **Description**, **Solution**, **See Also**).

What I would like to do is chop the file up even more and create

1. Separate CSV files based on the vulnerability **Name**. the actual file name does not have to be the name of the vulnerability it can remain static V001, V002, ...
2. Populate the separate files with the results based on each vulnerability **Name** (Host, Risk, CVE, Description, etc.). So in file V001 all affected hosts for V001 vulnerability will populate in that file and so on.

   ```
   $all = Import-Csv c:\scan.csv
   $all_with_none_removed = $all | Where-Object {$_.Risk -ne "None"}
   $Sumary_By_Vuln = $all_with_none_removed |
                     select Name, Host, Risk, CVSS, CVE, Description, Solution, 'See Also' |
                     Sort-Object Name
   $Sumary_By_Vuln | Export-Csv C:\final.csv
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could group your input by name and export each group to a separate file:

```
$all_with_none_removed |
    Select-Object Name, Host, Risk, CVSS, CVE, Description, Solution, 'See Also' |
    Group-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Export-Csv ($_.Name + '.csv') }
```

Comment: This works great but some of the file names are too long or have illegal characters. I get the following error 'Export-Csv : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:107
+ ... ct Name | ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Export-Csv ($_.Name + '.csv') }
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand'

Comment: So, check the value of `$_.Name` and fix that?

Comment: Yes i found the values giving the errors, the characters are <, /, and \ i just have to figure out how to remove or ignore special characters when creating the file names. Thanks for your help Ansgar!

Comment: I did the following to remove illegal characters but i am struggling with where to place this in the code you provided it just seems to not work correctly `$remillcharacters | ForEach-Object { $_.Name -replace '[\W]',''}`

i try to place it `$all_with_none_removed | Select-Object Name, Host, Risk, CVSS, CVE, Description, Solution, 'See Also' | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object { $_.Group ** -replace '[\W]',''** | Export-Csv ($_.Name + '.csv') }` but i dont think its right.

Also i cant do export -path because i get an error cannot convert value.

Comment: Replace [invalid path characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260418/1630171) with a valid character, e.g. an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You could first pull out all the distinct names from the data:

```
$Names = $all_with_none_removed | Select-Object Name -Unique
```

You then loop some code `foreach` (hint hint) of these names, filtering out the results you have found in a similar way to how you removed the no-risk results.

Sorry to not provide a full solution, but you're here to learn right?